# Multithreading in c using a thread safe random numbers

Tags: c, multithreading

I have been trying to get this to pass valgrind leak check and also pass in 2 billion random numbers and divide them between the threads.  I keep getting a seg fault once I get to 1 billion random numbers.  Where am I allocating wrong or what am I doing wrong?

```
struct thread
{
    long long int threadID; //The thread id
    long long int operations; //The number of threads
};

void *generateThreads(void *ptr)
{
    struct thread *args = ptr;
    struct random_data *rdata = (struct random_data *) calloc(args->operations*64,sizeof(struct     random_data));
    char *statebuf = (char*) calloc(args->operations*64,BUFSIZE);
    long long int i;
    int32_t value;

    for(i = 0; i < args->operations; i++)
    {       
        initstate_r(args->threadID,&statebuf[i],BUFSIZE,&rdata[i]);
        random_r(rdata,&value);
    }

    if(DEBUG > 1)
        printf("I am thread %lld with thread id %X\n", args->threadID, (unsigned int) pthread_self());

    free(rdata);
    free(statebuf);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long long int numRandoms;
    long long int numThreads;
    double timeStart = 0;
    double timeElapsed = 0;
    pthread_t *tid;
    struct thread args;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Number of Randoms> <Number of Threads>\n" ,argv[0]);
         exit(1);
    }

   /* Assign the arg values to appropriate variables */
   sscanf(argv[1],"%lld",&numRandoms); /* lld for long long int */
   sscanf(argv[2],"%lld",&numThreads); /* lld for long long int */

   /* Number of threads must be less than or equal to the number of random numbers */
   if(numRandoms < numThreads)
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"Number of threads must be less than or equal to the number of random numers.\n");
       exit(1);
   }

   /*Start*/
   long long int i;
   args.operations = numRandoms/numThreads;
   timeStart = getMilliSeconds();
   tid = (pthread_t *) calloc(numThreads,sizeof(pthread_t));

   /* value is the thread id, creating threads */
   for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
   {
       args.threadID = i;
       pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,generateThreads,(void *) &args);
   }

   /* Joining the threads */
   for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
   {
       pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
   }

   /*Output*/
   timeElapsed = getMilliSeconds() - timeStart;
   printf("%lf\n",(double)(timeElapsed/1000.0));
   free(tid);
   fflush(stdout);
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what `struct random_data` is, so we don't know how big it is. But, most likely the argument to `calloc()` exceeds the size that you can allocate as a single block on your computer. Another important question: Are you building this as a 32-bit or 64-bit program?

Comment: Can't you generate random numbers on the fly? `rand()` returns a 15-bit number but you can easily get a bigger one by, for example, `r = rand() + (rand()<<15);`

Comment: (off-topic) isn't a long long overkill for number of threads ? I understand that some people want to make their code future proof.

Comment: Why the `*64` in the `calloc` calls?

Comment: @GregHewgill local machine is 64 using OSX but I'm using ssh to run the program through my school's nodes... struct random_data was listed on the man page (see link) [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random_r.3.html)

Comment: @JS1 I was trying to follow examples that I found online that had a similar issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane We had to create our own thread id and use that as the seed for the random number and use a thread safe random number generator.

Comment: @dvhh You are right, it is overkill.  I was just trying different things to see if there was something I didn't understand correctly and that was one of them.

Comment: I think you might be running out of memory.  Try without the `*64` because you don't appear to need it.

Comment: @JS1 still running into the same issue without the *64.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Without knowing what `initstate_r` or `random_r` are, I don't know.  You're going to have to debug your program and try to figure out where it is failing.  Make sure to check the return values of all functions such as `calloc` and make sure none of them are returning NULL or an error value.

Comment: @JS1 I have added return statements for debugging and everything is returning as expected until 1 billion numbers and it gives me a seg fault.  The debugger tool has not helped me yet but I'm still working on it.  The initstate_r and random_r information can be found at [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random_r.3.html) fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured out what you were trying to do.  The problem was that whatever code you copied from used `initstate_r` in `main` to set up the states for all threads.  It called `initstate_r` once per thread to set up the rng for that thread.  But you copied that loop into each thread, so you were calling `initstate_r` many times per thread which is useless.  The `*64` was there originally to make each state occupy 64 bytes in order to keep them on separate cache lines.  You probably were referring [to this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000456/multi-threaded-random-r-is-slower-than-single-threaded-version).

Here is your function rewritten to make much more sense:

```
void *generateThreads(void *ptr)
{
    struct thread *args = ptr;
    struct random_data *rdata = calloc(1,sizeof(struct random_data));
    char statebuf[BUFSIZE];
    long long int i;
    int32_t value;

    initstate_r((int) pthread_self(),statebuf,BUFSIZE,rdata);
    for(i = 0; i < args->operations; i++)
    {
        random_r(rdata,&value);
        if(DEBUG > 1)
            printf("%d\n", value);
    }

    if(DEBUG > 1)
        printf("I am thread %lld with thread id %X\n", args->threadID, (unsigned int) pthread_self());

    free(rdata);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

By the way, the way you pass your arguments to your threads is wrong.  You pass the same `args` to each thread, which means they are sharing the same `args` structure, which means they each share the same `args->threadID`.  You should instead pass each thread its own `args` structure.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797664/what-is-the-most-correct-way-to-generate-random-numbers-in-c-with-pthread/31162121#31162121) provides thread safe pseudo-random number generator designed for __uint64/__uint128 integers using xorshift algorithm.

Additional properties:

- shared-reentrant
- lock-free
- thread-safe
- ultrafast
- seeded from two variant sources of enthropy